# Show WP7 application's tile?

Tags: windows-phone-7, background, icons, tile

How do I make the application's tile (big image) visible in the menu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visible on the home screen?  in the app list, tap and hold the item, you'll get a "pin to start" option.

Or do you mean how do you set it in your app?

Comment: Thanks for the manual way, but I am curious if it is possible programmatically. (manual is enough, tho)

Comment: @Vercas This is not possible programmatically. The tiles displayed, and their position, on the start screen are solely within the user's control.

Comment: yup, only the user decides what goes on his/her home screen.  (well, and the mobile operator who gets to set some stuff in the original phone image)

Answer (score 6):

The image shown in the list of all applications is called `ApplicationIcon.png` and the one shown when you pin an application to the main page is called `Background.png` when you create the project. Modify these files to contains whatever image you want; just keep their sizes the same. The defaults are 62x62 pixels for `ApplicationIcon.png` and 173x173 pixels for `Background.png`. You can rename these if you want, but IMO its not worth the trouble. Also, keep them at the root of the project, you can relocate `Background.png` and then modify `WMAppManifest.xml` to point to the moved file but this doesn't work for `ApplicationIcon.png`.

Finally, in the solution explorer, click on each file and look at the properties (in the property manager window, this can be launched from the Tools menu). Make sure the `BuildAction` property is set to `Content` and the `Copy to output` option is set to `Copy if newer` (or `Copy always`).

To answer the second part of your question, you cannot programatically pin your application to the start menu.

Comment: if you're doing games, i think you want to set your ApplicationIcon reference to your 173x173 Background.png since games show up as big icons in the games hub thing.

Comment: thanks! I was having the same issue. I uninstalled from emulator and rebuilt, and made sure the icons were set for content, and in rot and everything else. Bu then I saw the "(or Copy Always)" and I set that and they appeared. voted the answer up since it helped point me to a fix.